# simple combining of two tables into one containing the columns of both

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to combine two tables in a 1:1 manner?  It seems like what a `JOIN` really does is create all the possible combinations between rows in two tables, then use `ON` to filter out the rows that are not of interest.  But what I really want is to combine two arbitrary tables like so:

```
 a        b         a | b
---   +  ---   =>  ---+---
 1        8         1 | 8
 9        3         9 | 3
 7        4         7 | 4
 5        0         5 | 0
```

The individual tables might be formed by a selected or they might be literal values created by `SELECT`/`UNION`ing literal values.  The solution should not depend on any particular way that both tables are obtained, but can assume that both tables will always have the same number of rows.

For example, suppose the first column be found by:

```
SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY x ASC
```

And the second column be found by:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 0),(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 5 as B)
```

Now if I do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY x ASC) AS a,
    (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 5 as B)
```

I get every 16 rows returned, pairing every a value with every b value, when in fact I just want 4 rows as shown in the table above.  Furthermore, I can't think of an `ON` conditioner to make it filter out the rows I don't want because the tables don't share anything in common.

`UNION` won't work, because it unions rows together.  What I want to do is more like unioning columns together.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY x ASC) AS a,
    (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 5 as B)
ON
    a.rowid == B.rowid
```

But this only seems to work if both sub-selects were manually created (e.g. the same way as the second clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating 2 temporary tables with ID's and then join them based on a AUTO INCREMENT field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this Stack Overflow answer:

- [Unioning Two Tables With Different Number Of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)

What about this one?"

- [SQL - union two tables, each having a few unique columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601516/sql-union-two-tables-each-having-a-few-unique-columns)

In the OP's post, you give 4 rows from 2 tables with unique rows.  If you use a statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.a
UNION
  t2.b
```

it will yield you 4 unique rows (just as you asked).  See here for an explanation of how a `UNION` would work for you in this example b/c you have no duplicates of info in your 2 tables... while a `UNION ALL` would yield 8 rows, a `UNION` should yield 4 rows (in this case only):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)

Now, this may not work for other, non-unique rows, but that's not what you asked.

In any event, the 2nd link I supplied gives you examples and instructions for dumping one table into another, which is essentially the only way to do this, as a SQL statement is going to work relationally on 2 tables which is why you are having problems.

You are basically trying to combine 2 tables **WITHOUT** any real relationship between the 2 of them, so what you really want/need is to be doing a concatenation of some sort... and then reparse them back into columns.  You have a few options in this regard:

- It's best to use an ETL tool (or script) of some kind, then...
- concat into a text file perhaps,
- then reimport into a table using a column delimiter that you set/injected between the columns when you concatenated them.

Short of a tool, or an external script to concatenate your result sets as text files, try using the SQL examples that I provided in the links above.

Comment: I don't really understand what the first question is asking, but I don't think it is asking the same thing as I am.  The second question is using `UNION` which I believe is going to union rows, not columns.

Comment: it ***will*** union rows, that's right... however, in your example, all your rows are unique, so it should work

Comment: but a union is going to create 8 rows of 1 column each, right? whereas I need 4 rows of 2 columns each.

Comment: a **UNION ALL** will do that for sure.  But, a **UNION** will yield as few as possible, b/c it ***eliminates duplicates***.  So, in your case... with the data you provided in your question, it should be only 4 rows.

Comment: The fact remains that any of the Set operators combine rows from two tables and do not produce the two separate columns I need.

Comment: Estella, try to form a well rounded answer instead of firing different links on sight ;)