# How to reverse order of SQLite CTE

Tags: sqlite, reverse, common-table-expression

If I do a simple select, I can order the result using `ORDER BY`.  But I cannot do this with a  `WITH RECURSIVE` CTE, because I am using it to find a path from a leaf in a tree back up to the root, and the order that the CTE creates the result is not an order that can be obtained by sorting, therefore there is no `ORDER BY` I can reverse to get the reverse order.

The problem I have is, this constructs the results from leaf to root, but for a subsequent part of the query I need it to be in the reverse order, from the root to the leaf.  But I cannot construct the query this way because it would wind up following all branches in the tree instead of the single path that I need.  Thus, I need to somehow reverse the order of the resulting CTE.  How can I do this?

I have done a bit of looking and there are some similar questions for other (non SQLite) database which seem to suggest that the result of the CTE table doesn't actually have any defined order.  I am not sure if that is true for SQLite - I always see it output the table in the same child to parent order, and in fact there are other cases (such as in creating temporary tables, [as in a previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129726/simple-combining-of-two-tables-into-one-containing-the-columns-of-both)) where if the table were not guaranteed to have this property it would break the only possible solution rendering it an impossible problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#withorderby) says:

> An ORDER BY clause on the recursive-select can be used to control whether the search of a tree is depth-first or breadth-first.

However, you want to sort the ultimate output of the CTE.
This can be done easily because you are using a normal SELECT to access the CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE test1(id, parent) AS (
    VALUES(3, 2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT test.id, test.parent
    FROM test JOIN test1 ON test1.parent = test.id)
SELECT *
FROM test1
ORDER BY id     -- this sorts normally
```

Comment: It isn't guaranteed that the id field is greater for child than parent (I've actually moved to a more complex table where the primary key is composite and isn't autoincrement).  However, I'm thinking it would be possible to accomplish this with a different field that I always increment from parent to child (e.g. a "depth" field).

Comment: Yes, if you want to sort, you need some actual value to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple elements in your order by.  For example the following will order the tree by name after performing the depth first search.  Here I am sorting first by LEVEL descending then NAME ascending.  The output would be a sorted tree with children underneath the appropriate parent.

```
WITH RECURSIVE TEMPTREE (
        id,
        name,
        level
    )
    AS (
        SELECT flow_id,
               name,
               0
          FROM DATATABLE
         WHERE parent_id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATATABLE.id,
               DATATABLE.name,
               TEMPTREE.level + 1
          FROM DATATABLE
               JOIN
               TEMPTREE ON DATATABLE.parent_id = TEMPTREE .id 
         ORDER BY 3 DESC, 2 ASC
    )
    SELECT substr('..........', 1, level * 3) || name AS Name,
           id
      FROM TEMPTREE;
```