# mysql union different number of columns

Tags: mysql

I know union queries have to have the same number of columns.  I'm trying to get results from the table `comments` and results from the table `strings`, which has multiple joins.  How do i this correctly?  I haven't tested yet because i know i'll get an error with different number of columns.  Here are the two queries that i'm trying to combine.

query 1(strings)

```
SELECT sub.actionid as usersub, 
                ftable.`last-time` as lastvisited, updatetable.recent as mostrecent, parent.* FROM `strings` as parent 
        LEFT JOIN subscribe sub on sub.actionid=parent.id AND sub.userid=:userid
        JOIN followers ftable on ((ftable.sid=parent.sid AND ftable.page='1') OR 
        (ftable.sid=parent.sid AND ftable.position=parent.position AND ftable.page='0') 
        OR (ftable.profile=parent.starter AND parent.guideline='1')) AND ftable.userid=:userid
        JOIN `update-recent` updatetable on 
        ((updatetable.sid=parent.sid AND updatetable.position=parent.position AND updatetable.pageid='0')
        OR (updatetable.profile=parent.starter) OR (updatetable.pageid=parent.pageid AND parent.pageid!=0))
        WHERE ftable.userid=:userid AND parent.deleted='0' GROUP BY parent.id
```

query 2(comments)

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE viewed='0' AND (`starter-id`=:userid OR respondid=:userid)
```

I'd like to order the results by the timestamp column `posted` (most recent) `ORDER BY posted DESC`

How do i union these queries?

Comment: There are no aggregating functions in your query, so what's the point of GROUP BY?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unioning Two Tables With Different Number Of Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You would want to select columns as `NULL` to take up for the empty space in certain tables.

Table A: (id, column1)

Table B: (id, column1, column2)

```
Select id, column1, null as column2 from tableA
UNION
Select id, column1, column2 from tableB
```

Answer (score 1):

Add empty columns (`null as columnName`) to the query that has fewer columns. You should avoid using `*` in this case, to have better control on order of columns in both queries.

Answer (score 1):

Another very dodgy way to get around the issue is to CONCAT_WS columns not shared between the tables e.g.

```
SELECT `r_id`, `r_added`, CONCAT_WS('###',`otherfield1`,`otherfield2`) as r_other FROM table1
UNION
SELECT `r_id`, `r_added`, CONCAT_WS('###',`otherfield3`,`otherfield4`,`otherfield5`) as r_other FROM table2
```

You can then programmatically reconstruct that data e.g.

```
$rother = explode("###", $row['r_other']);
```

**Very bad way to get at this data** but might get someone out of a fix. You could even change the separator e.g. #t1# #t2# search the string for that to workout what table the concatenated data is from.