# union with multi table with different column how to combine

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table dental 
    column are(Title,publisher,keyword,subject) and another 
   table i have elsevier
   column are(author,title,journal,publisher,abstract,keyword) 
   and third table sage
   column are(author,title,journal,publisher,abstract,keyword).
    the question is how can i combine the these tables through union all so i          can get the data from the database from all three tables.
    i can not use join only option i have union so suggest if if there is any solution regarding  this

when i use :

```
select null author, Title, null journal, publisher, subject as abstract, keyword  from table1 
    union 
select author, title, journal, publisher, abstract,keyword from table2

select null author,Title,null journal,publisher,null abstract,subject as abstract,keyword from dental 
     where  (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' or Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' or abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Subject LIKE '%Bastone%') 
   union 
select  author, title,  journal, publisher, abstract,keyword, null subject from elsevier 
     where(Author LIKE '%Bastone%' or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' or Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' or abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Subject LIKE '%Bastone%')
```

getting this error

> ```
> #1054 - Unknown column 'Author' in 'where clause'
> ```

Comment: Look at the answer regarding ["mysql union different number of columns"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867152/mysql-union-different-number-of-columns?rq=1). I'd suggest their approach ("null" values for not overlapping columns)

Comment: not getting proper reference cos both table have diffrent numbers of columns

Comment: However, the approach can be generalized.. look at my proposed answer below

Comment: see at the top i attached ur query structure with my query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A viable approach could be:

```
select null author, Title, null journal, publisher, null abstract, keyword, subject  
  from table1 
 union all
select      author, title,     journal, publisher,     abstract,keyword, null subject 
  from table2
 union all
select      author, title,      journal, publisher,    abstract,keyword, null subject 
  from table3
```

If some of those fields are just "synonyms" (e.g. abstract and subject) you could make them return in the same column just by aliasing them (e.g. "abstract as subject"). See below example:

```
select null author, Title, null journal, publisher, subject as abstract, keyword  
  from table1 
 union all
select      author, title,     journal, publisher,     abstract,keyword 
  from table2
 union all
select      author, title,      journal, publisher,    abstract,keyword 
  from table3
```

**After clarification on the structure of the query**

If you need then to apply a where condition to the resulting tables, you'd better wrap them into a query.

Example:

```
select * from (
    select null author, Title, null journal, publisher, subject as abstract, keyword  
      from table1 
     union all
    select      author, title,     journal, publisher,     abstract,keyword 
      from table2
     union all
    select      author, title,      journal, publisher,    abstract,keyword 
      from table3
) as table_union
where author like '%string%'
```

If, for some reason, you can't wrap the whole query (i.e. for limitations of your querying framework), you could wrap the single queries.

So, your original query could be written as:

```
select * from (
select null author, Title, null journal, publisher, null abstract, keyword, subject  
  from dental
 union all
select      author, title,     journal, publisher,     abstract,keyword, null subject 
  from elsevier
) as table_union
where (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or abstract LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%'
       or Subject LIKE '%Bastone%'
)
```

or:

```
select * from (
select null author, Title, null journal, publisher, null abstract, keyword, subject  
  from dental
) as dental_2
where (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or abstract LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%'
       or Subject LIKE '%Bastone%'
) 

 union all

select * from (
select      author, title,     journal, publisher,     abstract,keyword, null subject 
  from elsevier
) as elsevier_2
where (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or abstract LIKE '%Bastone%' 
       or Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%'
       or Subject LIKE '%Bastone%'
)
```

Comment: Could you please paste the code you're testing? Maybe you're forcing mixed case names?

Comment: can i post u the query here  which i made though ur structure

Comment: Yes, or better yet, add it to your original question

Comment: edited the question with your structure see at the top

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer to reflect your issue. Basically, now that you've united all the tables, you don't need to apply the same where condition to all of them. You can wrap them and apply the condition just once (if for some reason that's not possible, you could wrap them singularly and apply the where condition after the subquery)

Comment: a lil bit agree bt u r not getting my point..bydway its helpful

Comment: Hope the latest modifications help you.. otherwise, could you please explain me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use alias name for second table and third table as first table fields name

Comment: (select null as author,Title,null as journal,publisher,null as publisher,null as abstract, keyword,subject from dental where 1) union (select author,title as Title,journal,publisher,abstract,keyword,publisher,keyword from elsevier where 1) union (select null as author,Title,null as journal,publisher,null as abstract,keyword,subject from sage where 1)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'Author' in 'where clause'  getting this error