# MySQL Multiple SELECT in use with WHERE

Tags: mysql, select

Currently I'm working on my datatables and trying to build a small overview with pie-charts and stuff. For this I need to multiply different columns and get the sum of them (like `SUM(episodes*length) AS full_length_sum`).

The problem is that I also need the sum of some specific entries also. So I came up with the `WHERE` operator. Unfortunally this is used for the whole Table. So I moved to google and came up with the `UNION` to get multiple "different" SELECT. Unfortunally I'm doing something wrong and dont know what exactly.

I just do this as a little hobby and my skills in MySQL and PHP are very low. Most I "learn" from trial and error. So I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

**Here is my current code without the multiple selects:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error . "<br>");
}

$sql = "
    SELECT id, id_mal, title, genre, studio, release_date, lastwatched_date, cover, type, progress, episodes, watch_counter, status, comment, rating, favorite,
    (episodes*length) AS full_length, (watch_counter*episodes*length) AS current_length,
    SUM(episodes*length) AS full_length_sum, SUM(watch_counter*episodes*length) AS current_length_sum
    FROM dt_series";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $sum_fl = bcdiv($row['full_length_sum'] / 60, 1, 2);
        $sum_cl = bcdiv($row['current_length_sum'] / 60, 1, 2);

        $conn->close();
```

**and beginning from `$sql = "` my try to get multiple selections:**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT id, id_mal, title, genre, studio, release_date, lastwatched_date, cover, type, progress, episodes, watch_counter, status, comment, rating, favorite,
    (episodes*length) AS full_length, (progress*length) AS progress_length, (watch_counter*episodes*length) AS current_length,
    SUM(episodes*length) AS full_length_sum, SUM(watch_counter*episodes*length) AS current_length_sum
    FROM dt_series 
    UNION 
    SELECT progress, length, 
    SUM(progress*length) AS progress_length_sum 
    FROM dt_series 
    WHERE status = 0";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I have also tried it only with the `SUM(` in the second like:

```
  UNION 
    SELECT 
    SUM(progress*length) AS progress_length_sum 
    FROM dt_series
```

So.. this is not working for me and I wonder why.

PS: I know this is probably not a secure way to handle sql (someone told me) but I only use this on my .htaccess protected webspace and no important data is stored in there.

**edit:**

First of all: thanks do everyone who is trying to help me. I will try to give you further informations about what I want to try.

So overall I have this table 'dt_series' in which I store all relevant informations about the series I have planned to watch or allready have completet watching.

For this I also have a column for the length of an episode which I call `length` and and for the quantity of episodes, called `episodes` and also a counter (if I have watched a series completly with all episodes the counter goes one up) called `watch_counter`.

I have build a simple Pie-Chart using this information I've noted above. What I got working is that this Pie-Chart currently is displaying the total length of (watchtime) of all series I have stored (quantity of episodes * episode length / `SUM(episodes*length) AS full_length_sum`). After this I've addet the total time spent watching (watch counter * episodes * length / `SUM(watch_counter*episodes*length) AS current_length_sum`).

Now I want to add the value of the allready watched episodes length of a series which is not completed. Currently I have watched 16 episodes of a series which has 37 episodes. So I cant take the `SUM(watch_counter*episodes*length) AS current_length_sum` because the watch_counter is still 0. And even if it would be 1 I would get the total length of the whole series but only have watched 16 episodes.

But I have a column in the table which is called `status` and I also have column called `progress` for the count of episodes I've done watching. So my Idea is that I want to get `SUM(progress*length) AS progress_length_sum` So I get the sum of the current watched episodes * episodes length where the status is '0' (watching).

Comment: no insecurity comes with user input, but using always **prepared statements** with parameters is good practice. Could you also provide some data and what you expect should appear?

Comment: sure thing. so I want to multiply the columns 'progress' with 'length' as a new column 'progress_length_sum' for each row in the table where 'status' is '0'. Then I want the total sum of the new column 'progress_length_sum' and provide it as variable in php like I've done with ' $sum_fl' and ' $sum_cl' so I can use it in the JavaScript for the pie-char.

Comment: please edit your questuion for new information.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've edited my Questionen.

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious thing wrong with the SQL, even before we get to the UNION, is the aggregate expressions (SUM) in the SELECT list, along with columns (non-aggregate expressions)  which aren't in a GROUP BY clause.

All of the rows that match the condition in the WHERE clause are getting collapsed into a single row, and the values of the first eighteen expressions are *indeterminate*, they will come from some row in the group, but there is no guarantee which row they will be returned from.

(We expect there is more than one row that matches on the "status=0" condition, with the first query, it doesn't matter if zero, one or more rows match, the query will return exactly one row, or ...

With a different setting of `sql_mode` including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, we would get an error returned. And that behavior is more is more consistent with most other RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, et al.)

It's not really possible to give advice about adding a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` to the existing query, when it looks like the query is broken.

Typically, when we get aggregates, we are getting a single row for the whole set...

```
SELECT SUM( t.length * t.episodes )  AS full_length 
  FROM dt_series t
 WHERE t.status = 0
```

Or, we get aggregates for some subsets of rows, bunching rows together into groups

For example, by the value of studio

```
SELECT t.studio
     , SUM( t.length * t.episodes )  AS full_length 
  FROM dt_series t
 WHERE t.status = 0
 GROUP
    BY t.studio
 ORDER
    BY t.studio
```

---

Without a specification, better communicated by sample data and expected output, it's not really possible to give advice about adding UNION.

We can note that the UNION and UNION ALL operators require two sets to contain the same number of columns, and the same (or compatible) datatypes

As an example:

```
 SELECT 1 AS col_one, 'two' AS col_two, buckle*myshoe AS col_3
   FROM ...
  WHERE ...
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 5 , 'six', pickup_sticks 
   FROM ...
  WHERE ...
```

But again, I can't recommend adding a `UNION` set operator without understanding what it is we are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` does not work with different quantity of columns.
Have a look at this post that can also help you:
[mysql-union-different-number-of-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867152/mysql-union-different-number-of-columns)

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I've tried it and currently its "working" but I dont get data back (outputs 0). Another user here noticed that there are cases where UNION or UNION ALL cant used or can cause trouble by messing with the output. So I think I get this here - not sure.

Comment: ok, at least the problem with the union seems to be solved which is the main question.