# MySql joining 2 queries with no common field

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries for 2 tables

```
select something,something2 from database.table1 where id=1

select something from database.table2 where id=2
```

How can I join the results from this 2 queries?

I need this because I want to get the results in just 1 mysqldatareader.

edit: the 2 queries don't have equal number of columns. Sorry

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Join them with a union

Comment: use select comments have different number of columns/

Comment: You may need to select empty fields so columns line up

Comment: There are many different ways to join tables. Could you give an example of a result set?

Answer (score -1):

If there is an equal number of columns and they contain the same data types, you can use "UNION" to merge them.

```
select something from database.table1 where id=1
UNION 
select something from database.table2 where id=2
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: use select comments have different number of columns

Comment: You can reduce the column selection in the table with more columns. Do the data types match?

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to join tables. You didn't elaborate what result set you would expect. So my guess is the cartesian product:

```
SELECT t1.something, t1.something2, t2.something
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
    WHERE t1.id=1 AND t2.id=2;
```

This will select one tuple like this:

```
("something from t1", "something2 from t1", "something from t2")
```

Comment: Markus, you failed to read the question properly. Perhaps next time before down voting everyone who has good reading comprehension, you could reread the question to make sure you know what's going on. The OP was specifically trying to join RESULTS, not TABLES. Which is exactly what UNION is for.

Comment: So could you please elaborate why you think there is a difference between tables and result sets? In [my comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) there's no difference to the join operation.

Comment: Well, if I have a table with 10 fields and I only select 3 of them, those are my results, not the table. You can see the difference here... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07d5f/4

Comment: We definitely have different understandings of the terms *relation*, *join* and *union*. A result set of any operation on a relation (table) is still a relation. I have only one understanding of joining two relations. Union is a different. As you suggested, I read the OP again. Given the fact of two distinct relations I still keep my opinion that a selection on the cartesian product makes the most sense (=join).

Comment: No we agree on what those terms mean. I completely understand WHY you say what you do. But what I'm trying to do is answer the question based on what the OP has said ("How can i join the results from this 2 querries[sic]."). He did not say he wanted the tables joined nor did he state that they could be. He wanted the results from two queries in a single result set. Thus a UNION.

Answer (score -2):

if you have different number of Columns then Add extra columns as null for the table having less columns like

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Null as Col4, Null as Col5 from Table2
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)

Comment: why downward. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns

Comment: I didnt downvote you someone else did..currently testing your answer

Comment: +1.  You don't technically even have to alias the nulls, since the column names from the first `SELECT` in the `UNION` will be used for the entire result set and the subsequent values are placed wherever they appear, by ordinal position. The nulls can be inserted in whichever position they are needed.

Answer (score -2):

Your table have not equal field,so you cant use UNION
so may this can't help you:

```
 (select clm1 from database.table1 where id=1)
    UNION
    (select clm2 from database.table2 where id=2);
```

but maybe this is your answer:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* from table1 as t1,table2 as t2 where t1.id=1 AND t2.id=1;
```