# Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why am i gettin this error  Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

```
$query = "
SELECT DISTINCT s.studentid, s.fname, s.lname, s.studentcode, s.courseid, u.id 
FROM students as s,
courses as c, users as u, studentgrade as sg 
WHERE s.courseid = '$id' and u.id = (SELECT id FROM courses WHERE courseid = '$id') and u.id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$nombre')
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(sg.assignmentpoints) as sum
           FROM assignments as sg
           WHERE sg.courseid = 185
           GROUP BY sg.courseid
 ";
```

Comment: Well, it's perhaps time you learn what a UNION is before using it? Or at least now you're getting an error? - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: You can't use different fields in select clause when using `UNION`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2309943/367456

Comment: @hakre If you don't want to help at least let others help

Comment: @CarlosPerez: The way you ask the question is not helpful. Can you at least explain why you thought that UNION is what you're looking for to solve the problem? Unless you share a minimum about what you tried and what you expected and what happened instead it's not possible to offer you any help.

Comment: @hakre I don't if a UNION is what i need, but Im trygin to find a way to do it. What Im trying to do is to select name, last name ... and in the saem query select from a different table the sum of two assignment so I can assign a grade to a user

Comment: So what is the relation between those two tables? the corseid or the userid? or both? First tell/see about the relations.

Comment: @hakre no relation at all :/

Comment: Your just wrote: *so I can assign a grade to a user* - now you wrote there is no relation at all. If there is no relation between grade and user, I wonder how you want to manage it to assign a grade to a user.

Comment: @hakre - I'm with you; I wouldn't want a grade belonging to a different person.  Especially if I didn't take that class!  This query also appears to be possibly open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) - please learn how to mitigate this, or suffer the wrath of your end users.  Or just, y'know, suddenly find everybody is passing every course...

Answer (score 1):

```
(
        SELECT DISTINCT s.studentid, s.fname, s.lname, s.studentcode, s.courseid, u.id 
        FROM students as s,
        courses as c, users as u, studentgrade as sg 
        WHERE s.courseid = '$id' and u.id = (SELECT id FROM courses WHERE courseid = '$id') and u.id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$nombre')
)
```

- Query A.

```
(
SELECT SUM(sg.assignmentpoints) as sum
           FROM assignments as sg
           WHERE sg.courseid = 185
           GROUP BY sg.courseid
)
```

- Query B.

Query A should return the same number of columns as the request B.
So In your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.studentid, s.fname, s.lname, s.studentcode, s.courseid, u.id 
FROM students as s,
courses as c, users as u, studentgrade as sg 
WHERE s.courseid = '$id' and u.id = (SELECT id FROM courses WHERE courseid = '$id') and u.id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$nombre')
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(sg.assignmentpoints) as sum, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''
           FROM assignments as sg
           WHERE sg.courseid = 185
           GROUP BY sg.courseid
```

I think you need [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), not [Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.studentid, s.fname, s.lname, s.studentcode, s.courseid, u.id 
    FROM students as s,
    courses as c, users as u, studentgrade as sg 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM assignments 
    GROUP BY courseid
    ) as asg on asg.courseid=s.courseid
    WHERE s.courseid = '$id' and u.id = (SELECT id FROM courses WHERE courseid = '$id') and u.id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$nombre')
```

Comment: Thank you this will help me with what Im trying to do (y)

Comment: Now my number of columns match, but when I try to display the sum says that the sum is undefined

Comment: I think you need Join, not Union. Post edited.