# Creating a union statement

Tags: mysql, union

I'm trying to create a select stament that makes use of the union statement as well. I have 3 tables and 2 of them has 14 column where as the third has 19 columns. Is there a way to create a union statement that accepts a table that doesn't have the same amount of columns

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unioning Two Tables With Different Number Of Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Unioning Two Tables With Different Number Of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)

As mentioned by [Kangkan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118500/kangkan) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309966/363217):

"Add extra columns as null for the table having less columns like

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Null as Col4, Null as Col5 from Table2
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

Either reduce the number of columns from the larger table (using SELECT) or increase the number of columns in smaller tables (using column aliases).

Option 1 (assuming t1 and t2 have 3 columns):

```
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM t2
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM t3) AS t
```

Option 2 (assuming t3 is the larger table and has 5 columns):

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, 1 as c4, 1 as c5 FROM t1
UNION
SELECT c1, c2, c3, 1 as c4, 1 as c5 FROM t2
UNION
SELECT * FROM t3
```