# PHP Multiple database table search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

i am trying to use UNION to search same keyword in multiple tables.

My code looks like:

```
$con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
    $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_vin WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM national_register_sk WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql ) union ( $sql2 );
    $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<th>Progress</th>";
        echo "<th>Claim number</th>";
        echo "<th>Make</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "<th>View</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>24</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['claim_number']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['license']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['vin']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"detail.php?id=".$row["id"]."&action=detail\">detail</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
             } 
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
```

Ofc its throwing error with unexpectred union but i am not sure how else i should write it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `union` is a SQL keyword, so u should add into your SQL and not in your PHP => `$sql = $sql1 . ' UNION ' . $sql2;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, unfortunately it throw error :
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\audahistory\class\data2.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\audahistory\class\data2.php(26): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\audahistory\audahistory.php(43): Data->fetchByVin() #2 {main} thrown in`

Comment: You try to union two tables that have a different number of columns.

Comment: Yea thats right, but how else i can do that multiple search? because i cant edit tables

Comment: You can declare NULL column to equilibrate the tables, as said in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns

Comment: Thanks for this advise, but its incredible big tables, is there any other way to avoid it?

Comment: I try to add something like
http://pastebin.com/xk3ze1Nx
still same problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your union must be in the SQL statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_vin WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1 UNION SELECT * FROM national_register_sk WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: SQL statement is a better word for this than query string tho

Comment: Right, sorry for the mistake :)

Comment: Hey mate, thank you for answer as well, this is what i try first but i thought its wrong. Because when i try it and even right now its throw error :
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\audahistory\class\data2.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\audahistory\class\data2.php(26): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\audahistory\audahistory.php(43): Data->fetchByVin() #2 {main} thrown in`

Comment: As I commented above, you try to union two tables that have a different number of columns.

Comment: yea man, i read your comment, but not sure how else i can fix it then :)