# Using multiple queries in one foreach when tables don't have matching column count

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a timeline, that shows statuses and jobs from a company, I have 2 seperate tables:

`Jobs` and `Statuses`

Both tables don't match column numbers, so I cannot use a union all (to my knowledge). How can I go about doing what I want?

Jobs:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_user` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_description` text NOT NULL,
  `job_duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_category` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `job_employer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_enabled` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `job_startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `job_enddate` date NOT NULL,
  `job_wage_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `job_wage` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `job_requirements` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `job_application_start` date NOT NULL,
  `job_application_end` date NOT NULL,
  `job_experience` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `job_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `job_live` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_street` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_zip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `job_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_lat` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_long` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `job_address_differs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `job_featured` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `jobs`
--

INSERT INTO `jobs` (`job_id`, `job_company`, `job_user`, `job_name`, `job_description`, `job_duration`, `job_category`, `job_employer`, `job_enabled`, `job_startdate`, `job_enddate`, `job_wage_type`, `job_wage`, `job_requirements`, `job_application_start`, `job_application_end`, `job_experience`, `job_date`, `job_live`, `job_address_name`, `job_address_street`, `job_address_city`, `job_address_zip`, `job_country`, `job_address_lat`, `job_address_long`, `job_address_differs`, `job_type`, `job_featured`) VALUES
(26, 1, 29, 'Senior Web developer', 'Test', 1, 'CEO & General Management;Information & Communication Technology', '1', 0, '2016-04-07', '2017-06-11', 'weekly', '12.50', '1', '2016-03-31', '2016-05-19', '2', '2016-03-31 06:07:19', 'live', 'london', 'london', 'london', 'london', 'United Kingdom', '51.4654277', '-0.2547461', 0, 'fulltime', NULL),
```

**status table**

```
CREATE TABLE `timeline_status` (
  `timeline_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeline_status_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeline_status_privacy` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'public',
  `timeline_status_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `timeline_status_profile_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeline_status_post` text NOT NULL,
  `timeline_status_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timeline_status_enabled` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `timeline_status_postedby` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeline_status_post_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `timeline_status_image_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `timeline_status`
--

INSERT INTO `timeline_status` (`timeline_status_id`, `timeline_status_user`, `timeline_status_privacy`, `timeline_status_type`, `timeline_status_profile_user`, `timeline_status_post`, `timeline_status_date`, `timeline_status_enabled`, `timeline_status_postedby`, `timeline_status_post_type`, `timeline_status_image_id`) VALUES
(47, 29, 'public', 'user', NULL, 'test', '2016-04-16 00:47:50', 'enabled', 0, '', 0);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is merging it all in one timeline, in a random organisation, I could do 2 foreaches, but that means one would be on top, and the other at the bottom.

So is this possible in any way?

Comment: So `job_user` is link to `timeline_status_user`? right??

Comment: So can you elaborate on what you want the output to be please

Comment: Also a few more rows in timeline_status woudl be useful for testing

Comment: I just want to select both tables and all rows to use for my foreach, then I can use an if statement to see which ones a job ans which ones a status then I can display the design accordingly

Comment: i this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This single query would produce one line containing both job and status row data. One row for each `timeline_status`

This should make your foreach loop easier to process than having 2 seperate results to keep in line with each other, you just need to look for a change in the job_id, to know when the row relates to the next job.

```
SELECT j.*, s.*
FROM jobs j
    JOIN timeline_status as s ON s.timeline_status_user = j.job_user
ORDER BY j.job_id
```

Of course the query would be more efficient if you limited the select to just those columns you actually want to use in the following processing.