# SQL Server, How to create two select statement in one table

Tags: sql-server

I make two select statements with different result sets,
Please help me to make those two select statements show the their result in one table,

```
DECLARE @EmpID INT

SELECT @EmpID = SubCategoryId
FROM dbo.Product
WHERE ProductId = 13

SELECT Product.ProductId
    , Product.ProductName
    , Product.ProductPrice
    , Product.ProductQuantity
    , Product.SubCategoryId AS ForUpdate
    , SubCategory.SubCategoryName
    , SubCategory.SubCategoryId
FROM Product
INNER JOIN ProductUnderCategory
    ON ProductUnderCategory.ProductId = Product.ProductId
INNER JOIN SubCategory
    ON ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId = SubCategory.SubCategoryId
WHERE Product.ProductId = 13

SELECT Property.Propertyid
    , Property.PropertyName
    , ProductProperties.PropertyValue
FROM Property
LEFT JOIN ProductProperties
    ON Property.PropertyId = ProductProperties.PropertyId AND ProductProperties.ProductId = 13
WHERE Property.Propertyid IN (
        SELECT PropertyId
        FROM CategoryProperty
        WHERE CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId = CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId AND CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId = @EmpID
        )
```

Comment: Are you using mySQL or MS SQL Server?  You have both tags.

Comment: Do you want to combine all rows from both result sets?  If so, the columns would need to "line up" and you don't have the same number of columns being returned.

Comment: If this is SQL Server (I don't know about mysql) then you will need a UNION but as Morpheus said the columns of the two queries need to match.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder it works the same in MySQL.

Comment: Morpheus,OldBoyCoder, Uueerdo Thank you all for your help. I use MS SQL Server

Comment: What do you want your combined result set to look like?

Comment: Tab Alleman, i want the result set to look like one table with columns that the select statements get

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309966/3854195 ?

Comment: It isnt sufficient to say you just want one table with columns as per your current queries. You need to DISPLAY an example of the `expected result`, and that should be based on examples if the interim results you got from each query do we can trace the logic. That means you should spend some time preparing the question so it can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the properties for each product (not a union, but a join).  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @EmpID INT

SELECT @EmpID = SubCategoryId
FROM dbo.Product
WHERE ProductId = 13

SELECT Product.ProductId
    , Product.ProductName
    , Product.ProductPrice
    , Product.ProductQuantity
    , Product.SubCategoryId AS ForUpdate
    , SubCategory.SubCategoryName
    , SubCategory.SubCategoryId
    , Property.Propertyid
    , Property.PropertyName
    , ProductProperties.PropertyValue
FROM Product
INNER JOIN ProductUnderCategory
    ON ProductUnderCategory.ProductId = Product.ProductId
INNER JOIN SubCategory
    ON ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId = SubCategory.SubCategoryId
LEFT JOIN ProductProperties
    on ProductProperties.ProductID = Product.ProductID
left join Property
    ON Property.PropertyId = ProductProperties.PropertyId 
    and Property.Propertyid IN (
        SELECT PropertyId
            FROM CategoryProperty
            WHERE 
              CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId = CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId
              AND CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId = @EmpID
            )
WHERE Product.ProductId = 13
```

Comment: It's working, Thank you so much Chris Steele, God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do something like the following - if a column doesn't exist in the 1st select you need to include whatever value is appropriate and must name the column. if a column doesn't exist in the subsequent selects then simply return null/''/0 or whatever you need as a value;

```
select Product.ProductId, Product.ProductName, Product.ProductPrice, Product.ProductQuantity,  '' as someColumn,  ....
from ....
union [all]
Select   Property.Propertyid,  Property.PropertyName,    ProductProperties.PropertyValue,  NULL (for ProductQuantity), ProductProperties.someColumn
from .....
```