# Merge two columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

T1

[image]

T2 result from unpivot T1

[image]

Unpivot query:

```
SELECT LocM, convert(varchar,[Date],112) as DateKey, FinanceCode, Amount
FROM SalesDetail
UNPIVOT
   ([Amount] FOR [FinanceCode] IN([Sales],[Wages])) AS P
```

T3

[image]

How to join/merge T2 with T3 so the result will be like:

```
StoreCode | FinanceCode | DateKey  | Amount
070       | Wages       | 20160131 | 3533
070       | Sales       | 20160131 | 833
070       | 0000        | 20160131 | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want such union of records for all dates, not only for 20160131.

Why don't you simply do UNION ALL on T2 and T3, using proper column ordering?

E.g.

```
SELECT StoreCode, FinanceCode, DateKey, Amount from T3
UNION ALL
SELECT LocM, FinanceCode, DateKey, Amount from T2
```

You can wrap it in a subquery and add `ORDER BY` if you want rows from some category to be next to each other.

Comment: what if the amount of each table columns is not the same? for example what if t2 have 4 columns and t3 have 5 columns

Comment: C'mon, that's a basic SQL thing. If you want to UNION ALL things with different # columns, you add constants with the value you want to see in missing columns. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns