# Two Excel Sheets to One Recordset

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vb.net-2010

I can successfully put data from one Excel sheet into the recordset, we'll call it `rs`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to append `rs` to add data from another Excel sheet to it.

Is this even possible? I've searched around and some people say it's not. The sheets are in the same workbook. Is there someway I could...

`"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A4:BM7]"` and `"SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$A4:BM7]"` in one query leading to one RecordSet?

Thanks for the advice ahead of time!

EDIT:

Both Sheet's first field is an ID so I was thinking something like...

`"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A4:BM7] JOIN [Sheet2$A4:BA7] ON A_ID = A_ID")`

but didn't have any success.

Fields in First Sheet: `A_ID` is first ... Around 25 others

Fields in Second Sheet: `A_ID` is first ... Around 30 Others

I want my recordset to contain `A_ID` along with the corresponding 55 others pulled from both the first sheet and second sheet.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql

Comment: Please edit the question and elaborate what are the fields in the first and the second datasets, and what fields do you want to be in resulting recordset?

Comment: UNION query could help

Comment: @omegastripes updated

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I tried a union query but it gave an error saying the number of columns in the two selected queries did not match `"Select * from [Sheet1$A4:BM7] Union SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$A4:BA7]")`

Comment: add some blanks to the first one, so select *,'','','','' as they are different sizes

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Googling it, less than 1 sec, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns.  Are you trying to get like Common column, sheet 1, sheet 2 or all of sheet 1 then all of sheet 2 underneath?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav all of sheet one, and then all of sheet two on the right of that

Comment: so you need a join :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  qualify the the fields that are being joined.

> "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].A_ID = [Sheet2$].A_ID"

I prefer using table aliases

> "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] as t1 LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] as t2 ON t1.A_ID = t2.A_ID"

**Note:** I didn't specify the sheet address in my queries `[Sheet1$A4:BM7]`.  If there is only a single list on the worksheets then you shouldn't need specify the address.

Comment: There's a single list, but the sheet has a title author, etc. on the top. Would specifying the sheet addresses cause an error of any sort?

Comment: @Bob I would say that it's technically better to specify the address but if the address isn't correct then an error will be thrown: `Error -2147467259 This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet.`. If it works without specifying the address then I wouldn't bother.