# Purpose of '0' before column name

Tags: mysql

I just wanna to know that , what's the **purpose of 0 before column name** , As I'm new to this field so help me understand things clear and in a better way. My working query is given below and the rows are mentioned which doesn't make sense to me. Thanks.

**0 sdebit_amount**,

**0 scredit_amount**,

**0 scredit_amount,**

```
SELECT 
MONTH AS month,
ROUND(IFNULL(scredit_amount,0),2) AS purchase,
ROUND(IFNULL(sdebit_amount,0),2) AS cash_paid
FROM 
(SELECT 
MONTHNAME(sc.scredit_date) as month,
IFNULL(SUM(sc.scredit_amount),0) AS scredit_amount,
0 sdebit_amount
FROM
sup_credit sc 
WHERE YEAR(sc.scredit_date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(sc.scredit_date) 

union all

SELECT 
MONTHNAME(sd.sdebit_date) as month,
0 scredit_amount,
IFNULL(SUM(sd.sdebit_amount),0) AS sdebit_amount
FROM
sup_debit sd
WHERE YEAR(sd.sdebit_date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(sd.sdebit_date)

union all

SELECT
 MONTHNAME(tpr.date) as month,
 0 scredit_amount,
 IFNULL(SUM(tpr.sub_total),0) sdebit_amount
 FROM
 tbpurchase_return tpr WHERE tpr.method='CREDIT'
 AND YEAR(tpr.date) = YEAR(NOW())
 GROUP BY MONTH(tpr.date)
 ) ABC
 group by month
```

Comment: `0` - value, `scredit_amount` - column alias. `UNION` requires the same number of fields in the rows you join.

Comment: can u explain a bit more please, and refer some article thats make my concept better...

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns.

Comment: Search MySQL Union

Comment: It's just a dummy value for that column in the subquery in the `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar means if there is no value exist on that specfic date than it will return `0` ?

Comment: The `credit` table only has credit information, no debit information. The `debit` table only has debit information, no credit information. When you combine them with `union`, you need a placeholder for the missing columns.

Comment: Than if have attache one more table e.g `xtable` thorugh `UNION` than i have to place `dummy value` in both `credit and debit table` as ` 0 xamount'`... is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is combining a table with credit records and a table with debit records using `UNION`. The credit table doesn't have a `debit_amount` column, and the debit table doesn't have a `credit_amount` table. The combined table needs both these columns. So the query adds a `debit_amount` column with `0` when it selects from the `sup_credit` table, and adds a `credit_amount` column with `0` when it selects from the `sup_debit` table.

Then the outer query sums everything together.

Comment: Than if have attached one more table e.g xtable thorugh UNION than I must have to place `dummy value` in both credit and debit table as `0 xamount`... is it ?

Comment: Yes. All the subqueries in a union have to return the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

The `SELECT` clause can contain one or more ***select_expr*** separated by comma. A ***select_expr*** is an expression (composed using table columns, literal constants, operators and functions).

It can have an alias; an alias is an identifier that follows the expression and can be optionally introduced by the `AS` keyword.

In your example, `0 sdebit_amount` is the same as `0 AS sdebit_amount` and it means: select the value `0` and use `sdebit_amount` as the name of this column in the result set. The result set will contain a column named `sdebit_amount` whose value is `0` for all rows in the result set.

Similar, `ABC` before the last `group by month` is an alias of the table generated by the two [`UNION ALL` statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) (the outermost set of parentheses). While a select expression alias is optional, it is mandatory for [derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html) (subqueries that appear in the `FROM` clause of a bigger query).