# SQL -SSMS- bringing data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help figuring out how to combine data from two tables and bring that data into a new table. A union won't work because the two tables don't have the same number of columns.

The first table column names are:

```
Code, Description, V21, V22, V05, 2018Payment, CM2018Payment, Rx2018Payment
```

The second table column names are:

```
Code, Description, V21, V22, V23, V05, 2019Payment, V22_2019Payment, V23_2019Payment, Rx2019Payment
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question to include details of the tables, the DDL for each with comments for each column should give enough info for us to help.

Comment: Please specify the details with the design.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns

Answer (score 2):

You can still work with `union` :

```
insert into newtable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, null as col4
    from table1 t1
    union all
    select t2.col1, null, t2.col3, t2.clo4
    from table2 t2;
```

However, here you just need to ensure the type conversations.

Comment: I used a UNION ALL following your sample query above and it gave me an error message: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @snoosan, check that the nuber of columns in the top and bottom queries are the same. Just count the number.