# How to achieve a similar result as OUTER UNION CORR in PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to achieve a similar result to the one shown in the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524364
However, it seems Postgresql does not support `OUTER UNION CORR`. Is there an alternative to this command?

Comment: Postgres does support natural joins, and perhaps this would meet your requirements.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you could just go with [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309966/6464308) from the question in your link.

Comment: IMHO `NATURAL FULL JOIN` should do the trick. (but I hate NATURAL)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'd prefer not to do that as I'm connecting at least 5 tables so it'd get messy fast

Comment: @wildplasser thanks, I will look into it! Why do you hate Natural tho?

Comment: The problem with `NATURAL` joints is that the result can change unpredictably if you add a column to a table.

Comment: I manually assigned a static non-matching id for one of my table (eg. `NULL`) and `FULL OUTER JOIN` them with based on that non-matching key. The result seems to achieve something similar to `OUTER UNION CORR`.