# SQL Union NULL Columns without explicitly list column names

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have two tables which are pretty wide (30 columns) but have very similar schema (20+ columns shared across both tables). I want to union those two tables together but want the new table to have all the fields from both tables.

Similar to the idea from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns).

However, the challenges arise when I start writing the queries that I have to specify all the columns from each table and not only that, but also use NULL to fill in the columns that is only present from the other table.

Like this:

```
select
    commoncolumn1, 
    commoncolumn2, 
    table1_only_column1, 
    NULL as table2_only_column1
    ...
from table1
union all 
select
    commoncolumn1, 
    commoncolumn2, 
    NULL as table1_only_column1, 
    table2_only_column1
    ...
```

from table2

This query gets really long as the number of columns increases and also not quite robust to schema changes. Is there a better way of union two tables which auto fill NULLs for non-present tables?

I am using Impala/Hive but if there is an ANSI way of doing this, that will be great!

Comment: You can do 

               select * from table1
               union all
               select * from table2

as long as they have the same number of columns and you extend both tables together. If one is extended you match the column in the other.

If the tables have common data you can join them on maybe you could do a cross join then group

Comment: Depending on your usage scenario you could create views for the two tables and combine these two in a UNION. I would only recommend this if you need UNIONs for the same set of columns multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#UNION_operator) (emphasis mine):

> In SQL the UNION clause combines the results of two SQL queries into a single table of all matching rows. The two queries must result in the **same number of columns** and compatible data types in order to unite.

So in short, you must specify `NULL` for non-applicable columns. You could script something to generate the SQL, or use the same column (with another column indicating which attribute it is), but you're kind of limited.

Not being familiar with Hive/Impala, there might be better options there.

For what it's worth, [here's the MySQL reference page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) for `UNION`. Interestingly, it doesn't explicitly state that the same number of columns is required (although that might just be because it's assumed).

As @AlexM notes, `SELECT *` might be an option. However, you want to be careful  with this, since the order of the columns might change, or new columns might be added, which would break the `UNION` query (standard warnings against using `SELECT *`).

Comment: I agree, based on what I have seen so far, there isn't anything in place but write a small script to auto generate the query.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, SQL UNION will match columns by ordinal position, not by name.  If the name of a column is identical in both SELECTs then that is also the name for the column of the result.  If not, then the column name for the result is "implementation-defined".

The meaning/consequence of all of this is that the onus is on you to beware of ***both*** the ordering of the columns in your SELECTs ***as well as*** the identical naming of those columns (if you want subsequent reference to those columns in the result of the UNION to be possible by using a name instead of a column number).

That's what the standard mandates compliant implementations to behave like, so you have very little chance of finding an implementation that can relieve you of the sufferings this causes for you.