# Two tables union

Tags: sql

I need to join two tables, example below:

```
table 1

K a b c
P x x x
P x x x
P x x x

table 2

K a b c 
P x x x
P x x x
P x x x

Final table

K a b c d e f
P x x x . . .
P x x x . . .
P x x x . . .
P . . . x x x
P . . . x x x
P . . . x x x
```

All the unions I've tried don't get my result properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: You are searching for [`OUTER UNION`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524364/5070879)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: Also you should post some of the queries you have tried and outline whst was wrong with them.

Comment: I see you are new in stack overflow, You should check all answers and mark as correct answer whatever solve your problem and you think answered you completely.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, in my opinion, is to use `full join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on 1 = 0;   -- never true
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try other answers also, This one particularly answer your question and is faster than join. Because there is no where condition

```
SELECT t1.p, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, '0' d, '0' e, '0' f
FROM table1 t1 
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.p, '0' a, '0' b, '0' c, t2.a d, t2.b e, t2.c f 
FROM table2 t2
```