# How to merge two tables with a different amount and order of columns in SSMS?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I have one large table with ~10,000 rows of data and 100 columns that I want to continuously update. The problem is that the files I will use to update (.csv) often are in different orders or contain extra/missing columns. If there are extra columns in the update I am fine discarding them, but I want the remaining columns to match up exactly, even if some are missing or out of order.

I know that there is a solution in creating a select and simply listing all columns, but I am looking for something more elegant/foolproof. Many of the examples I have seen work well enough using MERGE, UNION, or JOIN but I can't get them to work for this much larger dataset, which is why it has been giving me so much trouble. I am not very experienced with SQL so I would appreciate some additional padding to the explanation.

Where ABCD are columns and 1 is data: Here is the master table

```
a b c d
1 1 1 1
```

Here is the update table:

```
b c d e
1 _ 1 1
```

Only imagine that there are 100 columns and 100 rows to append to the 10,000 stored.

Desired:

```
a b c d e
1 1 1 1 
_ 1 _ 1 1
```

Or even

```
a b c d 
1 1 1 1
_ 1 _ 1
```

e:
This answer is exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem possible in TSQL
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524364/11777090

Answer (score 0):

do union all

```
select a,b,c,d,0 from table
union all
  select    0,b,c,d,e from table
```

Comment: Yes but what I'm looking for is a way to not have to list columns because it will often change and it is not very feasible to alter the order to match the source and destination for 100 columns. Such that designing 0,b,c,d,0 makes sense but doing 0,b,c,d,0,e,f,g,0,0,0,q,w,e,0,v,0c,0,q0,,w0d,0q... and on is what I'm trying to avoid.