# select different columns from multiple tables with common variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have three tables: - `food` - `toys` - `animals`

Each table has the columns - `id`, `color`, `item`

Table `toys` has additional columns - `sn`, `date` and more

Need to select `all` items from `all` tables with `color = red` and get them separately on client side

Something like:

```
$color = 'red';
$sql = "select * from food, toys, animals where color = :acolor";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":acolor" => $color]);
$food = $toys = $animals = '';
while($row = $st->fetch()){
        $food .= "<div class='food' data-id = " . $row['food.id'] . ">" . $row['food.item'] . "</div>\n";
        $toys .= "<div class='toys' data-id = " . $row['toys.id'] . " data-serial = " . $row['toys.sn'] . " data-date = '" . $row['toys.date'] . "'>" . $row['toys.item'] . "</div>\n";
    }
        $animals .= "<div class='animals' data-id = " . $row['animals.id'] . ">" . $row['animals.item'] . "</div>\n";
    }
$arr = [];
array_push($arr, $food, $toys, $animals);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**client side**

```
...
data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#wrapfood').html(data[0]);
$('#wraptoys').html(data[1]); 
$('#wrapanimals').html(data[2]);
```

As the final result:

`wrapfood` should have 5 divs with class `food`
`wraptoys` should have 9 divs with class `toys`
`wrapanimals` should have 21 divs with class `animals`

I tried various versions of the above code without success - getting errors on server side.

Any help?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: @Jerome - for example - `Invalid paremater number`

Comment: Don't select 3 tables at the same time, use `union` instead

Comment: @catcon - each select statement within UNION must have the same number of columns

Comment: ah, sorry I didn't read that requirement, you can add a null column for the table with less number of column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns

Comment: show your exact error message  and add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
$data = array('food' => array(),'toys' => array(),'animals' => array());
$color = 'red';
$foodSql = "select * from food where color = :acolor";
$toySql = "select * from toys where color = :acolor";
$animalSql = "select * from animals where color = :acolor";
$ft = $db->prepare($foodSql);
$tt = $db->prepare($toySql);
$at = $db->prepare($animalSql);
$ft->execute([":acolor" => $color]);
$tt->execute([":acolor" => $color]);
$at->execute([":acolor" => $color]);
$food, $toys, $animals = '';
while($row = $ft->fetch()){
        $food .= "<div class='food' data-id = " . $row['food.id'] . ">" . $row['food.item'] . "</div>\n";
}
array_push($data['food'], $food);

while($row = $tt->fetch()){
        $toys .= "<div class='toys' data-id = " . $row['toys.id'] . " data-serial = " . $row['toys.sn'] . " data-date = '" . $row['toys.date'] . "'>" . $row['toys.item'] . "</div>\n";
}
array_push($data['toys'],$toys);

while($row = $at->fetch()){
        $animals .= "<div class='animals' data-id = " . $row['animals.id'] . ">" . $row['animals.item'] . "</div>\n";
}
array_push($data['animals'],$animals);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then on client side you can access the data as

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#wrapfood').html(data.food);
$('#wraptoys').html(data.toys); 
$('#wrapanimals').html(data.animals);
```

Comment: thanks but I hope there is a way with a single `select` statement.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use a single select statement here is the solution... if you just want a color item and id

```
SELECT f.* from food f
     UNION 
    SELECT a.* from animals a
     UNION 
    SELECT t.id, t.color,t.item from toys t 
    WHERE t.color ="red" AND f.color="red" AND a.color="red"
```

if you want sn and date also

```
SELECT f.*,null,null from food f
 UNION 
SELECT a.*,null,null from animals a
 UNION 
SELECT t.* from toys t 
WHERE t.color ="red" AND f.color="red" AND a.color="red"
```

if your columns of the tales are in the same order as you specified id, color, and item then no problem with the above queries otherwise if the order is different arrange the column names in select statement accordingly...

now you can still use the above query if you want to separate it only client site in the single loop... just concatenate in the select statement.
here is what you can do...

```
SELECT CONCAT("#food",f.id), CONCAT("#food",f.color),CONCAT("#food",f.item),null,null from food f
 UNION 
SELECT CONCAT("#animals",a.id),CONCAT("#animals",a.color),CONCAT("#animals",a.item),null,null from animals a
 UNION 
SELECT CONCAT("#toys",t.id),CONCAT("#toys",t.color),CONCAT("#toys",t.item),CONCAT("#toys",t.sn),CONCAT("#toys",t.date) from toys t 
WHERE t.color ="red" AND f.color="red" AND a.color="red"
```

now we have concatenated the names of the tables with the column now when we display it we can easily filter them with their names...

this is how you filter them later on...

```
if(substr( $row['id'], 0, 5 ) === "#food"){
echo substr($row['id'],4);
}
```

Comment: can't check your solution now, but anyway - thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you want `t.color ="red" OR f.color="red" OR a.color="red"`