# UNION ALL over 2 large views SQL vs Python/Pands

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, union-all

How can I select distinct names of columns from 2 views?

I have a 2 large views with around 40 columns each created from various tables.

[Example given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309966/2119941)

shows how I would merge them if not other solution is available.

I'm creating table with `UNION ALL` , that's why I need to find way to select distinct columns from both views.

If there is some easy way of doing it in `DataGrip` or `SQL Server Management Studio` it would be nice.
And now long shot question with anticipated answer but I have to ask: any chance on running U-SQL over MS SQL 2016? 
Answer is probably "no" but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524364/2119941) seems awfully appealing because it would boil down everything on

```
t1 | union kind=outer t2;
```

If I use python/pandas for this on the server it would be just `df_union_all= pd.concat([v1, v2])` taken that I first have to extract  those views in dataframes.

Can someone give me performance comparison for those 2 cases (SQL vs python/pandas). Tables are around 100 milion (10 GB) and 20 milion (2 GB) rows/space large with mixed datatypes (varchar, nvarchar, int).

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh I don't think anything is missing, but I've added example which applies to my case.