# requestion... How to compare two tables?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to compare the database data in the php.

If the date and the amount match or the amount match, I would like to express it as False by comparing the table with the table in noti_card_data.

hospital_payment_data table

```
  id   |    chart_num    |    chart_name    |    store_mbrno   |card_amount_received  |        visit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1              1                1                 100012               6600                2020-05-08        
  14             2                2                 100012               11600               2020-05-08
  15             3                3                 100012               11600               2020-05-08 
  16             4                4                 100012               11600               2020-05-08
  17             5                5                 100012               11600               2020-05-08
  18             6                6                 100012               11600               2020-05-08
  19             7                7                 100012               11600               2020-05-08
  12             8                8                 100012               20000               2020-05-08




noti_card_data  table

  id      |         date             |    cmd    |    mbrNo     |    amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1             2020-05-08               success      100012         6600
  2             2020-05-08               success      100012         11600
  3             2020-05-07               success      100012         11600
  4             2020-05-06               success      100012         10000
  5             2020-05-08               success      100012         11600
```

If I send a query statement as follows, compare the values and train the TRUE values if they are the same, and FALSE values if they are different.
The desired value comes out, but the table I want to express is as follows.

in this my query

```
SELECT id, MIN(DATE) AS DATE, amount, (COUNT(*) = 2) AS result
FROM ((
SELECT id, hpd.visit AS DATE, card_amount_received AS amount, row_number() over (PARTITION BY card_amount_received
ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
FROM hospital_payment_data hpd
WHERE store_mbrno = '100012') UNION ALL
(
SELECT id, ncd.date, amount, row_number() over (PARTITION BY amount
ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
FROM noti_card_data ncd
WHERE mbrNo = '100012' AND cmd ='success')
) x
GROUP BY amount, seqnum
```

in this result
[image]

***but, I want result***

```
      id   |    chart_num    |    chart_name    |      card_amount_received  |        visit     |           date              |    amount
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1             1                1                      6600                  2020-05-08              2020-05-08              6600
      2             2                2                      11600                 2020-05-08              2020-05-07              11600
      3             3                3                      11600                 2020-05-08              2020-05-08              11600
      4             4                4                      11600                 2020-05-08              2020-05-08              11600
      5             5                5                      11600                 2020-05-08                null                  null
      6             6                6                      11600                 2020-05-08                null                  null
      7             7                7                      11600                 2020-05-08                null                  null
      8             8                8                      20000                 2020-05-08                null                  null
      9             null             null                   null                  null                    2020-05-06              10000
```

How do fix my query?

A user told me about the site.

> [Unioning two tables with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)

But it's not what I want.

I really don't know. How to modify my query. Let me know. Please.

Comment: It's impossible to link specific payments without unique ID for each. You can compare group values for `mbrNo`

Comment: See the Percona Toolkit.