# Union tables with different columns without specifying the columns - GBQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union

I want to union multiple tables together, in a similar fashion to how an Outer Union (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524364/11883834) would work.

I want to be able to do this without needing the specify the columns being selected in advance, i want to select all columns from all the tables and union them all together, with null values in columns that are added to tables without said column.

E.G.

```
Table1
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |
+---+---+

Table2

+---+---+
| b | d |
+---+---+
| U | 1 |
+---+---+

Table3
+---+---+
| a | d |
+---+---+
| B | Y |
| Z | 5 |
+---+---+

Resultant Table
+----+----+---+
| a  | b  | d |
+----+----+---+
|  1 | X  |   |
|  2 | Y  |   |
|    | U  | 1 |
|  B |    | Y |
|  Z |    | 5 |
+----+----+---+
```

Comment: isn't this answered already here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68004709/5221944 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid select the columns in the `SELECT` using `FULL JOIN`.  But you should still include them in the `FROM` clause:

```
select *
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (b) full join
     table3 t3
     using (a, d);
```