# Identifying unique columns between multiple table Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, view, union, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to identify unique columns between multiple table while doing 'UNION ALL'.

For example: Employee_1,Employee_2,Employee_3

```
Table1: Employee_1

|Emp_Id|Joined_Mnth|Store_NO | Marked_YR | 
+------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1    |March      |100020   | 2018      |
| 2    |April      |120004   | 2018      |
| 3    |January    |100032   | 2019      |
| 4    |October    |231009   | 2019      |

Table2: Employee_2

|Emp_Id|Store_NO | Marked_YR | 
+------+---------+-----------+
| 1    |100020   | 2018      |
| 2    |120004   | 2018      |

Table3: Employee_3

|Emp_Id|Joined_Mnth|Store_NO | Closed_YR | 
+------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1    |March      |100020   | 2020      |
| 2    |April      |120004   | 2018      |
| 7    |January    |100032   | 2021      |
| 8    |October    |231009   | 2019      |
```

Output in the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Employee AS
SELECT Emp_Id,Store_NO FROM Employee_1
UNION ALL
SELECT Emp_Id,Store_NO FROM Employee_2
UNION ALL
SELECT Emp_Id,Store_NO FROM Employee_3

|Emp_Id|Store_NO |  ==> Common columns between Employee_1,Employee_2,Employee_3
+------+---------+
| 1    |100020   |
| 2    |120004   |
| 3    |100032   |
| 4    |231009   |
| 1    |100020   |
| 2    |120004   |
| 1    |100020   |
| 2    |120004   |
| 7    |100032   |
| 8    |231009   |
```

How to identify common columns between all the above tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `information_schema.columns`:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name in ('Employee_1', 'Employee_2', 'Employee_3')
group by column_name
having count(*) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column list:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE ANY ('Employee_1', 'Employee_2', 'Employee_3')
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

---

EDIT:

Multiple tables could be combined by using `NATURAL FULL JOIN`(kudos to [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder), [related post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/lotcxf/is_there_such_a_thing_that_can_join_two/go7zmgl/)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Employee AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, 'Employee_1' AS tab FROM Employee_1) sub1
NATURAL FULL JOIN (SELECT *, 'Employee_2' AS tab FROM Employee_2) sub2
NATURAL FULL JOIN (SELECT *, 'Employee_3' AS tab FROM Employee_3) sub3;
```

It is kind of [OUTER UNION CORRESPONDING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524364/5070879) implementation.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid un-matched columns?

Comment: @K.Tom Using `NATURAL FULL JOIN`, no.